# how to match certain critierias that happened only on the selected time interval?

Tags: victoriametrics

I am trying to match interfaces that happened to have "test" keyword in the descriptions . This keyword appended only after link flap. I don't care for the "test"  occurred earlier and want to match only for the ones between now and now-2d.
I tried to use:

```
count_over_time(interface_stats_oper_status{description=~".*test.*"}[$__range] ==1))
```

but that gives me the interfaces have "test" in them even from before

Answer (score 1):

Do you use instant or range query? Please see the difference here https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#query-data

I believe, you're looking for something like the following:

```
count_eq_over_time(interface_stats_oper_status{description=~".*test.*"}[2d], 1)
```

sent to instant API.

Comment: thanks Hagent, in my case i think either one of them is ok since the data points even if missed couple of times the description would remain same. I tried your query too but it returns a gauge for each interface that has "test" in it and tried to wrap it count but somehow it still seems to be off.  What number 1 represent in that query?

Comment: 1 is a value we compare metrics with - see https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#count_eq_over_time